# What is LogonUser()'s token returned used for?

Tags: c++, winapi, return-value

What can you do with the token [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx) returns? And what is it used for?

```
BOOL LogonUser(
  __in      LPTSTR lpszUsername,
  __in_opt  LPTSTR lpszDomain,
  __in      LPTSTR lpszPassword,
  __in      DWORD dwLogonType,
  __in      DWORD dwLogonProvider,
  __out     PHANDLE Token
);
```

I just need a more general discription and real world uses of what the token is and how it works.

Thanks, -Pete

Comment: The MSDN link to LogonUser that you provided explains exactly what you can use it for.  I am confused as to why you ask.

Comment: @Zan Lynx, i didnt really understand the MSDN article, need a better (more general i guess) discription

Comment: Why do you need LogonUser function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MSDN says: "In most cases, the returned handle is a primary token that you can use in calls to the CreateProcessAsUser function". There are no reasons not to believe.

Sample: you could write your own `runas.exe`. Call `LogonUser` with username&password from command line. Then call `CreateProcessAsUser` to start program with selected credentials.